# Recurrent Neural Network - Vanishing Gradient in a network that has output at each time step

Tags: machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network, gradient

I am trying to understand the problem of vanishing gradient in RNN. However, it seems to me that this problem is not happen with a network that has output at each time step. Let's say we are trying to solve the binary addition problem:

```
011101 + 011011 = 111000

Which can be transformed to:

A    B    Result
1    1    0
0    1    0
1    0    0
1    1    1
1    1    1
0    0    1
```

So, with each pair of the input sequence, we have the output value, thus we can calculate the error and derivative at each point of time. And because of that, I don't think the Vanishing Gradient problem will happen on this kind of case. Am I correct?

Below is the Python code to demonstrate the binary addition problem with RNN

```py
import copy, numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

# compute sigmoid nonlinearity
def nonliner(x):
    output = np.exp(x) / (1 + np.exp(x))
    return output


# convert output of sigmoid function to its derivative
def nonliner_output_to_derivative(output):
    return output * (1 - output)


# training dataset generation
int2binary = {}
binary_dim = 8

largest_number = pow(2, binary_dim)
binary = np.unpackbits(
    np.array([range(largest_number)], dtype=np.uint8).T, axis=1)
for i in range(largest_number):
    int2binary[i] = binary[i]

# input variables
alpha = 0.1
input_dim = 2
hidden_dim = 8
output_dim = 1

# initialize neural network weights
synapse_0 = 2 * np.random.random((input_dim, hidden_dim)) - 1
synapse_1 = 2 * np.random.random((hidden_dim, output_dim)) - 1
synapse_h = 2 * np.random.random((hidden_dim, hidden_dim)) - 1

synapse_0_update = np.zeros_like(synapse_0)
synapse_1_update = np.zeros_like(synapse_1)
synapse_h_update = np.zeros_like(synapse_h)

# training logic
for j in range(100000):

    # generate a simple addition problem (a + b = c)
    a_int = np.random.randint(largest_number / 2)  # int version
    a = int2binary[a_int]  # binary encoding

    b_int = np.random.randint(largest_number / 2)  # int version
    b = int2binary[b_int]  # binary encoding

    # true answer
    c_int = a_int + b_int
    c = int2binary[c_int]

    # where we'll store our best guess (binary encoded)
    d = np.zeros_like(c)

    overallError = 0

    layer_2_deltas = list()
    layer_1_values = list()
    layer_1_values.append(np.zeros(hidden_dim))

    # moving along the positions in the binary encoding
    for position in range(binary_dim):
        # generate input and output
        X = np.array([[a[binary_dim - position - 1], b[binary_dim - position - 1]]])
        y = np.array([[c[binary_dim - position - 1]]]).T

        # hidden layer (input ~+ prev_hidden)
        layer_1 = nonliner(np.dot(X, synapse_0) + np.dot(layer_1_values[-1], synapse_h))

        # output layer (new binary representation)
        layer_2 = nonliner(np.dot(layer_1, synapse_1))

        # did we miss?... if so, by how much?
        layer_2_error = y - layer_2
        layer_2_deltas.append((layer_2_error) * nonliner_output_to_derivative(layer_2))
        overallError += np.abs(layer_2_error[0])

        # decode estimate so we can print it out
        d[binary_dim - position - 1] = np.round(layer_2[0][0])

        # store hidden layer so we can use it in the next timestep
        layer_1_values.append(copy.deepcopy(layer_1))

    future_layer_1_delta = np.zeros(hidden_dim)

    for position in range(binary_dim):
        X = np.array([[a[position], b[position]]])
        layer_1 = layer_1_values[-position - 1]
        prev_layer_1 = layer_1_values[-position - 2]

        # error at output layer
        layer_2_delta = layer_2_deltas[-position - 1]
        # error at hidden layer
        layer_1_delta = (future_layer_1_delta.dot(synapse_h.T) + layer_2_delta.dot(
            synapse_1.T)) * nonliner_output_to_derivative(layer_1)

        # let's update all our weights so we can try again
        synapse_1_update += np.atleast_2d(layer_1).T.dot(layer_2_delta)
        synapse_h_update += np.atleast_2d(prev_layer_1).T.dot(layer_1_delta)
        synapse_0_update += X.T.dot(layer_1_delta)

        future_layer_1_delta = layer_1_delta

    synapse_0 += synapse_0_update * alpha
    synapse_1 += synapse_1_update * alpha
    synapse_h += synapse_h_update * alpha

    synapse_0_update *= 0
    synapse_1_update *= 0
    synapse_h_update *= 0

    # print out progress
    if j % 1000 == 0:
        print ("Error:" + str(overallError))
        print("Pred:" + str(d))
        print("True:" + str(c))
        out = 0
        for index, x in enumerate(reversed(d)):
            out += x * pow(2, index)
        print(str(a_int) + " + " + str(b_int) + " = " + str(out))
        print("------------")
```

Answer (score 0):

If RNN need to backprop. through time to see past inputs in sequence in order to decide the output then the vanishing problem occurs. In your case RNN may not need to to use past memory of inputs in the sequence. The issues happen when RNN needs to remember inputs seen 10-20 items ago in the sequence.

One of the main reasons for vanishing of learning signal is that the signal propagates multiple times through same neurons and their activation function. Activation function like sigmoid or tanh has zero derivative at extremities so it increase the chance that derivative of backprop signal becomes zero.

LSTM solves partially the problem because the recurrent link does not have activation functions in its path.

Comment: Well, it actually need to use the past memory, but very close to the current input. I can see that most of the time, people refer to Vanishing Gradient problem in RNN is when the error/gradient back propagation through time, it getting smaller and smaller. But with the case when we have the output at each step, then we will be able to calculate error/gradient in that very time step, thus will be able to estimate the important of the input at that point of time. That why I think, RNN that has output at each time step will not suffer from Vanishing Gradient problem